# Race condition with RX using Buffer and StartWith

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I am trying to initially load the contents of a log file and tick this on an observable of `LogTailData[]` - so if the initial file contents are 20k lines, the first tick should be an array of length 20k.

After this, I want to buffer updates to the file by using a filewatcher and ticking back when a new line is received, buffering them up using RX.

I am using `StartWith()` to load the initial file contents, then the Buffered Observable should feed the updates.

However the problem I am having is if the initial data is large (eg 20k lines), then a file update seems to get ticked first on the observable, before the large array supplied by `StartWith`.

I'm wondering if the way `Buffer()` works means that if the timer elapses before the `initialFileLines` can be put on the observable, then you'll receive them out of order?

I need to guarantee that the initial data ticks first, regardless of how large the data set is.

My code

```
var initialFileLines = watcher.GetInitialData();

new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => watcher.StartFileWatcher(data => watcherSubject.OnNext(data), _cts.Token));

Stream = watcherSubject.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 100)
    .StartWith(initialFileLines)
    .Replay()
    .RefCount();
```

Comment: You really should avoid coding the way you are - try to avoid mixing Tasks and Rx. Did you try using my (almost) pure Rx solution? Also the use of `RefCount()` can lead to fragile observables - you need to ensure that you always have at least one subscriber at all times for it to be useful.

Comment: Your code, as presented here, has a race condition. Any changes after `watcher.GetInitialData()` but before `watcher.StartFileWatcher` are lost. You really need to provide a [mcve] to debug your code. Otherwise try my code on your previous question and see if that causes the error to go away. (And don't use `RefCount()`.)